# Изучение Java для создания Веб и мобильных приложений

Tags: java, книги

Здраствуйте. Хотел-бы начать изучение Java для создания в дальнейшем Веб и мобильных приложений. Какие книги, материалы могли бы посоветовать?

Comment: я не компилятор для java ищу,я спрашиваю,каким путём изучать javaдля моего случая

Comment: @Gorets я посмотрел и у вас вопросы есть из разряда погугли

Comment: да, за частую так и набираю рейтинг, дело в том, что это форум, где приятней отвечать на вопросы, типа "я вот тут чето делал, вот код, но почему-то не получается", а не на "я хочу и веб и мобилки, че делать?". Мне кажется мой совет хорош, по крайней мере он дает следующий шаг к твоей цели :)

Comment: @Boolean12345, как правило, ответ на этот вопрос есть тут --------->

Comment: Просто это действительно скучно каждый раз заново собирать эти [списки](http://hashcode.ru/questions/16644/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-java?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=16646#16646) [книг](http://hashcode.ru/questions/178607/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 3):

Напоминает вопрос: хочу научиться ездить на Ferrari - подскажите на какой модели лучше учиться Ferrari Dino или Ferrari Modena? ЗЫ: водить машину не умею.

**Ответ:** возьми любой убитости опель и научись ездить на машине!

Такой же и ответ: выучи обычную (vanilla) Java, а потом все остальное!

Answer (score 1):

Отличная книга для начинающих - [Head First Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Для базовых знаний:        Герберт Шилдт - Java

Для Web:                   Брюс У. Перри - Java сервлеты и JSP. Сборник рецептов

Для мобильных устройств :  http://www.javaportal.ru/mobiljava/articles/intro.html

 Symbian:                   Программирование мобильных телефонов на Java 2 Micro Edition

 Android:                   Android для программистов. Создаем приложения Дейтел П.,           Дейтел Х., Дейтел Э., Морган М. (2012)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понимать мобильную и веб разработку, нужно начать изучение с самих основ. Без них далеко не уедешь. На мой взгляд, лучшая книга Deitel, How to program Java. Про веб там немного написано, но поняв основы, можете смело открыть любую книгу и продолжить изучение языка. Удачи.